# How to fix Synology DSAssistant application start crash?

Tags: macos, crash, nas

The http://find.synology.com/ service doesn't find a newly connected Synology NAS device. For that case this website suggest to download "[Synology Assistant 5.2 5005 for Mac](http://global.download.synology.com/download/Tools/SynologyAssistant/5005/Mac/Synology-Assistant-5.2-5005.dmg)".

After opening the application straight from the DMG DSAssistant crashes.

Regression:

- When copying the application to the /Applications folder, DSAssistant also crashes when starting.
- After deleting the corresponding user preference file `~/Library/Preferences/com.synology.DSAssistant.plist` and emptied the trash, there is still the crash `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018` with application specific information `objc_msgSend() selector name: _getCString:maxLength:encoding:` on starting "Synology Assistant".

### DSAssistant crash report

```
Process:         DSAssistant [14226]
Path:            /Applications/Synology Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/DSAssistant
Identifier:      com.yourcompany.DSAssistant
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [195]
Responsible:     DSAssistant [14226]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2015-03-19 13:03:58.760 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  428F62AA-94ED-D642-051A-549F0657408A

Sleep/Wake UUID: 301A10AF-9772-48AC-9D95-E37348776148

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100377000 [ 3548K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Synology Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/DSAssistant

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: _getCString:maxLength:encoding:


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8b82b097 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8defa860 CFStringGetCString + 176
2   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000fa284 FHOSTIfaceInitMac + 1268
3   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000f8525 FHOSTUDPClient + 197
4   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100035eca CFindHostUDP::sendPktBroadCast(int) + 458
5   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100035f19 CFindHostUDP::slotSendPktBroadCast(int) const + 11
6   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000eeb7a CFindHostUDP::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 168
7   QtCore                          0x000000010117c06e QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) + 1566
8   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000f02c6 CAsstFinderWindow::signalRefresh() + 26
9   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000442f1 CAsstFinderWindow::slotRefreshTrigged() + 553
10  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100044317 CAsstFinderWindow::slotDelayedInit() + 19
11  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100010c79 CAsstWindowMain::slotFinder() + 67
12  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000ed52c CAsstWindowMain::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 230
13  QtCore                          0x000000010117c06e QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) + 1566
14  QtGui                           0x00000001004aea01 QAction::toggled(bool) + 49
15  QtGui                           0x00000001004afd0a QAction::setChecked(bool) + 138
16  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000106de CAsstWindowMain::slotActionToggle(CAsstWindowMain::PAGES) + 30
17  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100010f98 CAsstWindowMain::slotShowVisibleTab() + 92
18  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100012f6c CAsstWindowMain::CAsstWindowMain() + 546
19  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x000000010001307b CAsstWindowMain::CAsstWindowMain() + 9
20  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x000000010001f0e1 main + 2747
21  com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x0000000100003618 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d58be6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfaf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfdfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d58c662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9138c421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9138c136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d58be6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfaf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfdfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d58be6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfaf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfdfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d58b9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df83a03 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acf9899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acf972a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfdfc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d587a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d586d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df37f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df37539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df36e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8992405e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acf9899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acf972a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfdfc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: CFindHostUDP
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d58b9aa __select + 10
1   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x00000001000f8cc3 FHOSTUDPServer + 963
2   com.yourcompany.DSAssistant     0x000000010003815f CFindHostUDP::run() + 337
3   QtCore                          0x0000000101049dd4 QThread::setPriority(QThread::Priority) + 820
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acf9899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acf972a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8acfdfc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff5fbf6f00  rbx: 0x0000000109a9ad40  rcx: 0x000000000000003f  rdx: 0x00007fff5fbf6f80
  rdi: 0x00007fff886f75f9  rsi: 0x00007fff8839aa51  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbf69d0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbf6968
   r8: 0x0000000008000100   r9: 0x00007fff777eec20  r10: 0x00007fff8839aa51  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000008000100  r13: 0x00007fff886f75f9  r14: 0x000000000000003f  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff8b82b097  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000018

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100376ff7 +com.yourcompany.DSAssistant (???) <764B549E-21CE-7129-EBA0-B750B15C4042> /Applications/Synology Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/DSAssistant
       0x10042d000 -        0x100e43ff7 +QtGui (4.8.4) <A145BF76-42AB-AF91-C20D-8AE970E07ABB> /Applications/Synology Assistant.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
       0x101022000 -        0x1012faff7 +QtCore (4.8.4) <143F14D0-8F97-0C0E-585B-EBEE39B7AB63> /Applications/Synology Assistant.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
       0x101366000 -        0x1014a8fef +QtNetwork (4.8.4) <302A3F6C-633C-66C5-4DF6-AFAD90DABF5C> /Applications/Synology Assistant.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork
```

---

Any suggestions how to get the "Synology Assistant" application running?

Comment: Did you already try to remove any related .plist in your Preferences folder?

Comment: @klanomath I didn't. Once I removed `~/Library/Preferences/com.synology.DSAssistant.plist` and emptied the trash, the DSAssistant still crashes. The Synology DS112 also should become available on port 5000 which it doesn't. So the supplier advised me to sent in the Synology for repair.

Comment: @ProBackup before sending it back, could you possibly use any other machine (pc, laptop, other mac) to confirm it's the NAS which is causing the trouble?

Comment: @Rob It is definitely the Synology DS112 NAS that is causing the trouble. The repair sheet noted error 38, which despite all reset procedures couldn't be cured. After two months I received a brand new DS112 with similar issues, so that replacement Synology NAS will be sent back too.